# Rsync equivalent to scp -3

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

- Big Files on remote server A, of network A
- Big Files need to go to remote server B, of network B (accessible by VPN only)
- I can connect to both machines using rsa keys (configured in ssh config file for convenience) and a VPN client from my machine. I cannot change the keys used on either remote machine without a lengthy bureaucratic process for each.

This leads me to believe that my best course of action is to use my machine as the intermediary in an ssh bridge between these two machines.

My initial solution was to use a scripted series of *scp -3r* commands to move directories from A:A to B:B. However, even when using arcfour and with a stable network connection, this process is very slow and fragile.

Rsync has the capability to use *--partial* and *--append-verify* to resume processes when they are stopped, such that I can safely background this task on my machine and let it run for a few days with automatic restart when needed.

My question is: What is the rsync equivalent to *scp -3*? My attempted solution would be adapted by running

```
*rsync *???* user@A:path/to/big/files otheruser@B:path/to/desired/location -F /path/to/specific/.ssh/config
```

Alternatively, can you please suggest a method to accomplish this transfer given my constraints?

The method of last resort will be to mount these systems via sshfs and attempt to formulate a more amenable set of commands (much, much slower)

Thanks all

Comment: What is -3? I know of -1, -2, -4 and -6, but never heard of -3.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The BSD version of `scp` has a `-3` option, but GNU (/Linux)'s version doesn't. From [the FreeBSD man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=scp&sektion=1): "-3   Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the progress meter."

Comment: Thanks. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ssh to set up a tunnel so that rsync does the right thing.

On your local machine:

```
ssh -M -R 9999:serverB:22 serverA rsync -a --rsh "ssh -p 9999" /path/to/big/files/ localhost:/path/to/desired/location/
```

where "9999" is any port number you like, as long as it matches in both places, and "22" is the SSH port number on serverB (usually 22).

The `-R` option does a reverse tunnel that routes any program connecting to `serverA:9999` via your local machine through to `serverB:22`. (Actually, unless you add a "bind address", access is limited to local programs running on serverA, connecting to `localhost:9999`, so it's secure.)

The `--rsh "ssh -p 9999"` option tells rsync to use ssh with a non-standard port number (9999).

The `-M` option is probably not necessary, but it side-steps possible trouble with SSH connection sharing.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try let you know how it goes!

Comment: Will need to use * : 9999 : serverB : 22 in some cases, which is what I had to do. Thanks for the help